# cakephp saveMany using $fieldList (no form)

Tags: cakephp

I have this $data array: (built on a shell, not a form)

(debugged here)

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    (int) 0 => 's511013t',
    (int) 1 => 'id3422',
    (int) 2 => '1'
),
(int) 1 => array(
    (int) 0 => 's511013t',
    (int) 1 => 'id3637',
    (int) 2 => '1'
)
)
```

And using saveMany :

```
$this->Dir->saveMany($data, array( 'validate' => 'false', 'fieldList' => array('name','dir_dataname', 'project_id')));
```

Saving fails with no error.

I'm not sure if my $data array is well formatted, (I'm confused whether it should have another level) I built it from sql selects, etc. However it does contain all info I need saved, single model.

I'm running all this from a Shell and it does work to save a single record provided the field names everytime:

```
// this works
$this->Dir->save(array('name' => $data[0][0], 'project_id' => $data[0][2], 'dir_dataname' => $data[0][1]));
```

Already read Saving your data, and I'd really like to use saveMany and a fieldList due to my custom $data format. (I wouldn't like to have to insert field names on my $data).
(no sql_dump to show since is pretty cumbersome to get it from a shell task)

I've spent all evening trying to figure it out, can you point me in the right direction, Please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, the keys in each arrays are not valid fields in your database table. They should represent the same name as your table field.
When you build the array from sql, the output should look like these - an associative array:

```
array(
(int) 0 => array(
    (string) name => 's511013t',
    (string) dir_dataname => 'id3422',
    (string) project_id => '1'
),
(int) 1 => array(
    (string) name => 's511013t',
    (string) dir_dataname => 'id3637',
    (string) project_id => '1'
)
)
```

[Cake2.0 Docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveall-array-data-null-array-options-array)

```
$this->Dir->saveMany($data);
```

Comment: Thank you guys; What i'll do is iterate through my indexed array and build the associative structure; will get back. <?php
  //  ASSOCIATIVE array example
  $favourite = array(
    'OS'=>'Windows',
    'Forum'=>'phpBB',
    'Person'=>'Jay'
  );
?>

Comment: As suspected, I was using a bad $data structure. Goggled how to convert my indexed array to associative and then just save: ` foreach ($dataIndexed as $num_linea => $line_of_text) {
            $data[$num_linea]['name'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][1];
            $data[$num_linea]['dir_dataname'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][0];
            $data[$num_linea]['qca_interv'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][2];`
        }
Thanks  for the guidance. !

Comment: I looped my indexed array as follows. Do you have any suggetion to improve it? `foreach ($dataIndexed as $num_linea => $line_of_text) {
            $data[$num_linea]['name'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][1];
            $data[$num_linea]['dir_dataname'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][0];
            $data[$num_linea]['qca_interv'] = $dataIndexed[$num_linea][2];
        }`

Answer (score 0):

You can get the log via

```
debug($this->Dir->getDataSource()->getLog());
```

It looks as if you are using `fieldList` incorrectly. `fieldList` is a list of fields that are to be whitelisted for saving to the database, not a "mapping" like you are using.

You need to specify `field => value` pairs in the array for each record, not numerical indexes. I may be wrong, but I've never seen that and it doesn't look to be that way according to docs.

Comment: Thank you trigran, I got the sql log via your solution.